# JSON to resize picture based on another column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, view-formatting

I am using SharePoint Online and have a list

I have two columns:

- Department     (single line of text)
- Logo      (URL formatted showing as a picture)

I have formatted the Logo column as follows:

```
{"elmType":"div","children":[{"elmType":"img","attributes":{"src":"@currentField","title":"=if(@currentField == '', 'No picture available', @currentField)"},"style":{"position":"relative","top":"50%","left":"50%","width":"200px","height":"200px","margin-left":"-50%","margin-top":"0%"}}]}
```

What I want is that is the column called "Department" is "No1" then the Logo column will be 50% scale.

If the Department is "No2" then the Logo column will be "20%" scale.

If the Department is "No3" then the Logo column will be "35% scale".

---

Current JSON for gallery is:

{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json"
}

Column Name:  Department
Internal Field Name:  Title
Field Type:  Single Line of Text

Column Name Logo:
Internal Field Name:  Logo
Field Type:  Hyperlink or Picture    Format URL as Picture

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions based on department column like this:

```
=if([$Department] == 'No1', 500px, if([$Department] == 'No2', 200px, if([$Department] == 'No3', 350px, '1000px')))
```

For example:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
                "src": "@currentField",
                "title": "=if(@currentField == '', 'No picture available', @currentField)"
            },
            "style": {
                "position": "relative",
                "top": "50%",
                "left": "50%",
                "width": "=if([$Department] == 'No1', 500px, if([$Department] == 'No2', 200px, if([$Department] == 'No3', 350px, '1000px')))",
                "height": "=if([$Department] == 'No1', 500px, if([$Department] == 'No2', 200px, if([$Department] == 'No3', 350px, '1000px')))",
                "margin-left": "-50%",
                "margin-top": "0%"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note**:

1. You have to use the internal name of department column in JSON. You can get the internal name of your Image column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)
2. You have to show/include department column in list view.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Sorry doesnt work..... even when I amend the $Department to the correct internal column name $Title

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: plus non of the changes are affecting the "Gallery View"

Comment: If the internal name of column is "Title", you have to use, `[$Title]`. Make sure column is included in list view.

Comment: It is named correctly:    The problem appears to be on the line:       "$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json"

Comment: $ref '/properties/attributes/class' in 'https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json' can not be resolved.(768)

Comment: The schema errors are super annoying and I've submitted an update to get them fixed. However, they will have no effect on the format working. The schema validation is only done by the editor (and the error is a problem in the schema definition, not your JSON).

Comment: What @GaneshSanap has provided is a column format to be applied to a specific column in your view. If you would like a view format (to change the gallery view) that is a different request. However, you can reference a column format in the gallery view by switching to advanced and using the [`columnFormatterReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced#column-formatter-reference)

Comment: Thanks Chris - It is indeed the gallery view that I wanted... >  Sorry new to all of this....... So I know that I can amend the Gallery View and update the JSON.... so with this in mind and now have established that there are two columns  [$Title] where the name is....and [$Logo] where the URL to the logo is recorded.... what would be the correct JSO as above but for the gallery view to scale the Logo size based on the value in [$Title]

Comment: Can you add the complete JSON used in Gallery view formatting to your question? That will help us to provide you complete working JSON for gallery view. For gallery view, you should use `tile-formatting.schema.json` schema and not column formatting schema. Check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-gallery-formatting